# .sort return a map contains only one element

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a map contains 10 entries as shown in the 1st 10 lines in the "logs" section below. the map is populated with values as follows:

```
const featuresMap =  {};
for (const feature of features) {
  featuresMap[feature.getName()] = feature.getPriority();
  logger.info(': ++++++featuresMap ', featuresMap, '++++++');
}
 const sortedFeaturesPerPriority = this.sortFeaturesPerPriority(featuresPrioritiesTags);
logger.info('[delayOrchestration]: featuresPrioritiesTagsSORTED : ', sortedFeaturesPerPriority);
```

then i tried to sort the map according to its values, using the code shown in section "code_sorting".
The problem is that the sorting method in section "code_sorting" which is posted below is just return the last item and NOT a map contains all the items sorted.

please let me know how how to get a map conatina all the entries sorted according to the values of the map.

**code_sorting**:

```
sortFeaturesPerPriority(map) {
const mapSorted = Object
  .keys(map)
  .sort((a, b) => map[a] - map[b])
  .reduce((a, c) => (a[c] = map[c], a), {});
logger.info('[sortFeaturesPerPriority] mapSorted: ', mapSorted);
return mapSorted;
}
```

**logs**:

```
 INFO: [ProgramFactory] : ++++++featuresMap [["TEST",1]]++++++
 INFO: [ProgramFactory] : ++++++featuresMap [["TEST",1]]++++++
 INFO: [ProgramFactory] : ++++++featuresMap [["TEST",1]]++++++
 INFO: [ProgramFactory] : ++++++featuresMap [["TEST",5]]++++++
 INFO: [ProgramFactory] : ++++++featuresMap [["TEST",5]]++++++
 INFO: [ProgramFactory] : ++++++featuresMap [["TEST",2]]++++++
 INFO: [ProgramFactory] : ++++++featuresMap [["TEST",2]]++++++
 INFO: [ProgramFactory] : ++++++featuresMap [["TEST",2]]++++++
 INFO: [ProgramFactory] : ++++++featuresMap [["TEST",2]]++++++
 INFO: [ProgramFactory] : ++++++featuresMap [["TEST",6]]++++++

 //logs from the sorting method
[sortFeaturesPerPriority] mapSorted: {"TEST":6}
[delayOrchestration]: featuresPrioritiesTagsSORTED : {"TEST":6}
```

Comment: are you sure about the Java tag?

Comment: That's what `.reduce()` does, it narrows  an array down to a single value.

Comment: @Teemu Yes but that is not a bad thing as that single value can be array/object that will hold those sorted entries as it is in this case.

Answer (score 2):

it looks like every feature is returning the same name of 'TEST', so you're just overwriting the same property each time.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with that code. The fact that you are getting only the last `{"TEST":6}` is because you are creating properties of that object with all of them having the same name so that it will get overwritten each time, producing object with only one property. You can't have object properties like this:

```
const obj = {
    test: 1,
    test: 2
}
```

as the second `test` overwrites the first one.

Another issue is that even if you changed names of those properties, you are sorting them into a new object, where you have no guarantee that they will remain sorted as the ordering of the properties of an object does not need to follow the order in which they were created.

You could change the `mapSorted` like this and see if it fits your needs.

```
const mapSorted = Object
    .keys(map)
    .sort((a, b) => map[a] - map[b])
    .map(item => {
         return { [item]: map[item] }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a sorted structure, you need to use an array (and not an object).
There is several ways to proceed.

@Matus Dubrava's answer provides you an array containing sorted elements like {name: priority}.

Another way to proceed is to deal with an array from the beginning:

```
const featuresMap = [];
for (const feature of features) {
    featuresMap.push({name: feature.getName(), priority: feature.getPriority()});
}
const sortedMap = featuresMap.sort((a, b) => a.priority - b.priority)
```

Otherwise, if you just need sorted names:

```
const sortedNames = Object.keys(map).sort((a, b) => map[a] - map[b]);
```